# Phonegap3.0 $.ajax issue, not calling cross domain url

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am using Phonegap3.0 android build. There i am checking a url for authentication, whenever i run that url in browser its working. In my mobile app its throwing error with xhr.status "0".

When i alert the below code its giving error.

```
var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: getEmployeeURL,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false
            });
            ajaxRequest.done(function() {
                utils.hideLoading();
                alert("Authentication Success");
                //utils.navigate("#dashboardView");
            });

ajaxRequest.fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Authentication failed");
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(textStatus);
                utils.hideLoading();
            });
```

The above .fail method throws status as "0" and textStatus as "error". I dont know why this is not calling the url.

Find the below AndroidManifest.xml permission

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

I think cross domain have some issues with $.ajax but i set

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in the root config.xml and res/xml/ config.xml also

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

Before calling AJAX function you must wait to event „deviceready” to fire and add 2 code rows:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
Examplerequest();
}, false);
```

Comment: $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages is jqueryMobile right ? And what is that Examplerequest();

Comment: Got error 10-01 13:01:00.553: E/Web Console(21626): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'allowCrossDomainPages' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the  status is "0" but its equivalent to success that is "200" and it also depend upon jquery version.

So these links may help you

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/12/on-third-day-of-phonegapping-getting.html

http://samcroft.co.uk/2010/loading-data-into-a-phonegap-app/

Comment: So your telling to check with ajax.open with some status 0 || 200